Kubernetes Node port
I'm new to kubernetes
Can someone please help me understand the below scenario
Lets say I have two worker nodes (wn1 and wn2)
On wn1 I have a web application that I want to allow external access to so I've created a node port service service
Let's say I've selected the port 30002
This port is exposed on every worker node in the cluster even though the web application is only present on worker node 1.
All the resources I've gone through are mentioning reasons like high availability which I don't understand because the web application has to be present on multiple nodes to even talk about high availability

you typically have at least 2 instances of each app in kubernetes, to avoid single point of failure.

The port externally accessible on the workers connects to a Kubernetes Service, which can route to an eligible Pod no matter where it's running in the cluster.  Do you have a more specific question?
